# Solidity - Is there function to view list of holders addresses and each address attached tokens that it owns

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, erc721

Is there function to view list of holders addresses and each address attached tokens that it owns something like this

```
 - HOLDERADDRESS:   Tokens Id:
 - ADRESS1           1 , 24 , 
 - ADDRES2           9 , 6 , 
 - ADDRES3           1 , 24 ,
```

Answer (score 0):

First,`balanceOf(owner)` to get the nft balance from owner.
Second,`tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, index)` to retrieve the tokenId by index.
Note that the range of index is bigger equal to 0 and less than nft balance.
Ref:https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721